# Draw a line based on row and column

Tags: java, swing

Part of a task I'm doing requires me to draw a line between two dots based on the row and column given. My problem is, for a 3x3 square it'll draw the line perfectly for column 0, row 0. However, when I create a 5x5 square it is in the wrong position.

In both examples shown below, the line is drawn at column 0, row 0. Please note the images are relatively big, so it would probably be best not to embed them in.

[5x5 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmrF6.png)

[3x3 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qupss.png)

I am using Swing and the drawRectangle method signature is (x1, y1, x2, y2).
In this case, 'r' represents row, and 'c' represents the column value given in the arguments.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SwingMain extends JPanel {

       final static int SEPARATION = 200;
       final static int DIAMETER   = 25;
       final static int NBALLS     = 4;
       final static int WIDTH      = NBALLS * 250;
       final static int HEIGHT     = NBALLS * 250;
       final static int XSTART     = WIDTH / (NBALLS + 2);
       final static int YSTART     = HEIGHT / (NBALLS + 2);
       JFrame           frame      = new JFrame();

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SwingMain().start());
       }

       public void start() {
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
          frame.add(this);
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
       }

       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2d.setColor(Color.white);

          int y = YSTART;
          for (int r = 0; r < NBALLS; r++) {
             int x = XSTART;
             for (int c = 0; c < NBALLS; c++) {
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
                x += SEPARATION;
             }
             y += SEPARATION;
          }

          drawHorizontalLine(g2d, 0, 0);

       }

       public void drawHorizontalLine(Graphics2D g, int r, int c) {
           drawRectangle(g, 175 * (c + 1), 155 * (r + 1), 375 * (c + 1), 175 * (r + 1), Color.WHITE);
       }

       public void drawRectangle(Graphics2D graphic, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color c) {
           graphic.fillRect(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
        }

    }
```

I believe the issue has to do with the magic numbers I've put in for the drawRectangle. Rather, I should also incorporate the window's width and height. But, I'm just completely lost. The window width is based on (n * 250), n representing the number of dots. So in the 5x5 example, n = 6, whereas in the 3x3, n = 4. Also, if someone can suggest how to add some padding to the outer area of the circles which is even. Currently my window width and height formula is quite awful.

Also, the rather non-sense formula only works for column 0, row 0. So if I try to draw the line at column 0, row 2 will be shown below.

[Row 2, Column 0 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSwam.png)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I attempt to try make my questions as clear as possible. I just realised what you meant, I'll be making the changes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the issue has to do with the magic numbers

I would agree. But it also starts with incorrect values for your static variables.

1) "SEPARATION" is defined incorrectly. When you paint the ovals you increment the x/y values by the SEPARATION. But since the oval has a diameter of 25 the actual separation between the two ovals is only 175. So I would suggest SEPARATION should only be 175.

2) The WIDTH/HEIGHT then also uses random numbers. It looks to me like you want space before/after all the ovals. So the WIDTH/HEIGHT should be something like:

```
a) number of ovals * diameter, plus
b) (number of ovals + 1) * separation.
```

This will allow for equal space before/after each oval as well as the painting of each ball.

3) Now your XSTART/YSTART values are simply the SEPARATION value (175).

4) Now as you paint each oval you need to increment the next position by the DIAMETER + SEPARATION.

5) When you draw the Rectangle the width would always be constant. That is the DIAMETER + SEPARATION

6) The height would also be constant dependent on how thick you want the line

7) So all that remains is how to calculate the x/y location. For the first row/column you know the "x" will simply be the SEPARATION. For the next column you increment by the DIAMETER and the SEPARATION. So the general formula would be something like:

```
a) SEPARATION, plus
b) (column * (DIAMETER + SEPARTION))
```

The "y" calculation would be similar except is would use the "row" value in the calculation.

8) finally you would probably want to adjust the "x" value to paint from the center of one oval to the cent of the other so you would just add on the DIAMTER / 2. For the "y" value the adjustment would be something like (DIAMETER - line height) / 2.

None of the suggestions have be tested but I hope you get the idea that the only two numbers you really need to know are the DIAMETER and SEPARATION.

Note, if I was defining your class I would not use static variables. I would pass in the "balls" and "separation" as parameters. Then in the constructor I would calculate the other values.

Comment: Thanks for the quite detailed answer, I'm currently going through it and making the changes you suggested. However, I'm a little confused as in some for example 2a) you write "plus" at the end. What am I supposed to "plus"?

Comment: I gave you a mathematical formula in English (I could have written in all on one line if that is easier to understand). What is more important is that you understand the concept, that there is no need for "magic numbers". You just need the proper formula using the know values of "separation" and "diameter".

Comment: So think about is logically. If you have two balls, then you have a separation + oval + separation + oval + separation. I just broke that down into a formula that will work for "n" balls. It us up to you to verify the formula works. If not change it. But there should be no need to ever introduce magic numbers.

Comment: I understand that, I'm currently doing it step-by-step. So I'm working on creating the window width and height to the correct dimensions. Currently how I have it is the window width is set to (dots * (DOT_SEPARATION + DOT_DIAMETER) ) and the same for window height. Although, the height is so much bigger, despite being the same formula?

Comment: Actually, I think I may know why. As the window width and height are dependant on the number of "balls". Whereas, the X_START is always 175. That's why the square of balls aren't centered to the frame.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. If the number of balls is 8. Based on your answer, it will always draw the first circle from X_START which is 175. My goal is to have relatively even padding around the balls, which it currently doesn't (after implementing your answer).

Comment: `Currently how I have it is the window width is set to ` - If you want the dots centered on the panel, then that formula wrong as I just explained in detail. `Whereas, the X_START is always 175.` - no. The XSTART is always the DOT_SEPARATION (and so is the YSTART). Don't use magic numbers. The size of the height will be the same since you a using dots to represent the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: I'm not using magic numbers, I'm just re-stating what you said in your answer.  `XSTART/YSTART values are simply the SEPARATION value (175).` Your formula is wrong for the window width and height. I've implemented EXACTLY what you posted and this is the result - https://i.imgur.com/U70owYo.png

Comment: If you have the same horizontal and vertical separation, then the ball will be evenly spaced in both directions. If you want different separation then you need two parameters.

Comment: I want it evenly spaced in both directions.

Comment: `I've implemented EXACTLY what you posted` - I did not post any code. You interpreted my verbal description into code. Post your code in the form of an [mcve] so we can see exactly what your did. `I want it evenly spaced in both directions` - and my suggestion should do that.

Comment: I believe I interpreted your verbal description. I may be wrong, but let's go through the current example. So considering there are 4 balls, the diameter is 25 and separation is 175. In your answer you said `a) number of ovals * diameter, plus` which in numbers would be (4 * 25). So the window width would equal to 100. Whereas, the width was (4 + 1) * 175 equalling 875.

Comment: `So the window width would equal to 100.` No you are still interpreting it wrong. `a) number of ovals * diameter, plus` - that is only half of the formula, you also need to add in part "b". Again start with something simple and draw it on paper. Step through my suggestions with two balls. I don't just use the diameter!!! You also need to use the separation!!.

Comment: Okay, I guess the formatting didn't really help haha, sorry. I understood as a) representing the width, and b) representing the height...

Comment: `I understood as a) representing the width` - and I already replied I could have written "a" and "b" on one line if it is easier to understand. The point of all my comments is for you to understand the "concept", not the formulas, because the formula are not tested. How is it possible to calculated the with only based on the diameter? That would only work if the separation is 0.

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I was confused as to why I understood your formula to be that. I'm just doing this all on a piece of paper to better understand it, will get back to you on this. Thanks.